# C++ Prevent the opening of an output window

Tags: java, c++, jar

I have created a java program which has been compiled into a jar file.

Now to make it exe, I have a C++ script that launches the jar file.

It launches fine, but the black cmd screen (or C++'s default console window) stays open until the java program is closed.

Is there anyway for me to make it so the black output window doesn't open at all?

(I am using Code::Blocks IDE)

Comment: You don't need a C++ program just to run a Jar. You can just create a batch file with the following command:
java -jar [jar filename]

Comment: Yup, thats one of the naive solutions. But there are way too many reasons for not doing this. 1: batch files are .bat, not .exe, 2: if the java classpath hasn't been defined, this method screwes up.

Comment: You don't need a batch file; you can use a windows shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem once... if you are using Swing, try to run with "javaw", not "java", that worked for me.

Comment: i tried it, to no avail unfortunately. But thanks for trying though!